# Does Kafka Connect support enums?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

Are enum fields supported in Kafka Connect?   If not, what is the usual workaround?   I'm looking at the Kafka 2.6.0 ConnectSchema API here:  https://kafka.apache.org/26/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/connect/data/ConnectSchema.html

I'm trying to follow best practice by using the Confluent Schema registry (with AVRO), but can't seem to get my custom source connector to generate a schema containing enums to match an existing schema (the output topic has other producers besides the connector).  A work-around would be to simply use strings, but that undermines the whole point of a schema, doesn't it?

Comment: Enums in Avro are converted to strings in certain sink connectors, but there is a property named something like enhanced avro support in the AvroConverter which handles enums differently

Comment: Looks like "enhanced avro support" is specific custom code for the S3 Connector?   Only references I could find are https://github.com/confluentinc/schema-registry/issues/1306 and https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/kafka-connect-s3/configuration_options.html#connector

Comment: It should be in the Avro converter or deserializer

Comment: Looks like much of the logic is here:  https://github.com/confluentinc/schema-registry/blob/e4cdd0d49d5f20a8e2481a38d7a06a7fb21293e3/avro-data/src/main/java/io/confluent/connect/avro/AvroData.java#L777 .  Support appears shaky as schema equivalence based on doc and defaults might be problematic too:  https://github.com/confluentinc/schema-registry/issues/1042

Answer (score 0):

There is not an approach that works in general, but you can use a converter specific special configuration in the case of AVRO, and then you must also provide special hints via the enum field Schema properties.   I was able to provide the hints using a custom Connect Transform.

Configure the Connect converter with:

```
"value.converter": "io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter",
"value.converter.schema.registry.url": "http://registry:8081",
"value.converter.enhanced.avro.schema.support":  true,
"value.converter.connect.meta.data": false,
"transforms": "alarms",
"transforms.alarms.type": "org.jlab.kafka.connect.transforms.EpicsToAlarm$Value"
```

Then the custom Transform contains:

```
    final Schema prioritySchema = SchemaBuilder
            .string()
            .doc("Alarm severity organized as a way for operators to prioritize which alarms to take action on first")
            .parameter("io.confluent.connect.avro.enum.doc.AlarmPriority", "Enumeration of possible alarm priorities")
            .parameter("io.confluent.connect.avro.Enum", "org.jlab.kafka.alarms.AlarmPriority")
            .parameter("io.confluent.connect.avro.Enum.1", "P1_LIFE")
            .parameter("io.confluent.connect.avro.Enum.2", "P2_PROPERTY")
            .parameter("io.confluent.connect.avro.Enum.3", "P3_PRODUCTIVITY")
            .parameter("io.confluent.connect.avro.Enum.4", "P4_DIAGNOSTIC")
            .build();
```

[Full Transform Source](https://github.com/JeffersonLab/epics2kafka-alarms)

Comment: enhanced.avro.support reference:  https://docs.confluent.io/current/schema-registry/connect.html