# Does Kafka Connect support unions?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

The idea with the Kafka Connect [SchemaBuilder](https://kafka.apache.org/26/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/connect/data/SchemaBuilder.html) API is to define message schemas generically such that a serialization method (such as AVRO, JSON, ProtoBuff) can be configured independently via [Converters](https://kafka.apache.org/26/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/connect/storage/Converter.html).  However, it appears the AVRO SchemaBuilder is a superset of Connect as AVRO contains [SchemaBuilder.unionOf](https://avro.apache.org/docs/current/api/java/org/apache/avro/SchemaBuilder.html#unionOf--), whereas Connect does not.   Are there any workarounds for including unions in Connect schemas, perhaps similar workarounds to what was done with [enums](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64145935/does-kafka-connect-support-enums)?

Comment: Hints of a workaround exist in the source code of the AVRO converter, but I can't find any docs on it:  https://github.com/confluentinc/schema-registry/blob/e4cdd0d49d5f20a8e2481a38d7a06a7fb21293e3/avro-data/src/main/java/io/confluent/connect/avro/AvroData.java#L105

Comment: Created issue ticket:  https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-10625

Comment: Have you been able to use Avro Union schemas with Kafka Connect, using some work around or otherwise

Comment: @Joel - The only work around I've found is to include all possible fields and mark them all as optional.   You could probably create a Connect transform or Kafka Streams app to modify the message into an AVRO union